# existence of a minimal generating set of a finitely generated module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, solution-verification

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a commutative ring with unity. Then there eixsts a set of generators $\{m_1,...,m_n\}$ with $n$ minimal.

Proof) Since $M$ is finitely generated, there is $i$ such that $\{l_1,...,l_i\}$ generates $M$. Since for all $j\leq i$, there are $j$ elements generating $M$ or not, there exists a minimal such $n$.

I was wondering if the above is a correct argument.

Comment: in general, any module $M$ will admit a **rank**, defined as the smallest cardinal number $t$ such that $M$ has a generating system of cardinality $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is not correct.

For example, consider the abelian group $G=\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, regarded as a  $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Note that the set $A=\{3,4\}$ generates $G$, and no proper subset of $A$ generates $G$. But $A$ is not a generating set with the least cardinality, since for example, the set $B=\{1\}$ is also a generating set.

Instead, just use well-ordering . . .

Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated module.

Let $S$ be the set of positive integers $n$ such that $M$ can be generated by $n$ elements. By hypothesis, $S$ is nonempty, hence by the Well-Ordering Principle, $S$ has a least element.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!